# Add/remove item menu menuItem dynamically

Tags: android

I have a problem, I want to add item in a toolbar (material design) programatically .

This is a my menu :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

I know change text , color , background, and @override listener

```
toolbar.setBackgroundColor
toolbar.setTextColor
toolbar.setNavigationIcon
toolbar.setText
```

I don't know how I can add a menu ítem with a category " `android:orderInCategory="300`"

Thanks.

Note : I have all fragment, without 1 Activity

```
Tree - > Activity - > Fragment1(here add menu item) - > Fragment2(add/remove menu item) - > Fragmentx ..
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this Toolbar has option getMenu() which return menu

```
private static final String placeholder1="Something";
private static final int FIRST_ID=Menu.FIRST;
private static final int SECOND_ID=Menu.FIRST+1;


//To add an item
toolbar.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE,FIRST_ID,Menu.NONE,R.string.placeholder1);
toolbar.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE,SECOND_ID,Menu.NONE,R.string.placeholder2);

//and to remove a element just remove it with id
toolbar.getMenu().removeItem(FIRST_ID);
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all put the item you want to display/hide in your xml file.
Let's say it's "action_settings" as mentioned in your code, override the "onCreateOptionsMenu"

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
    if (yourConditionToShow) {
        item.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        item.setVisible(false);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think the condition should be tested in the method onPrepareOptionsMenu() instead

Answer (score 4):

If you do not have access to the toolbar, you can do the following:

1 - Add the item to the menu through onCreateOptionsMenu():

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_item_id, menu);

  return true;
}
```

2 - Create a boolean equal to true if the item must be visible

3 - Hide or show the item according to the value of your boolean in onPrepareOptionsMenu()

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

  MenuItem mi = menu.findItem(R.id.my_item_id);

  if(displayItem)
    mi.setVisible(true);
  else
    mi.setVisible(false);

  return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your **onCreateOptionmenu**, try this code

```
//menu.add("groupId", "ItemId", "OrderID", "title")
MenuItem item = menu.add(1, 100, 300, "Settings");
item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```

you can also add setting like xml. You can check by itemid(**"100"**) in **onOptionsItemSelected**.

If you don't want to use **100** as ItemId, you can create **ids** resource file. And can use like this,

```
//R.id.action_settings is from ids resource file
MenuItem item = menu.add(1, R.id.action_settings, 300, "Settings");
```

Answer (score 0):

1 Solution :

@Chitrang Thanks to idea, I solved with this line :

```
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_activity1);
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_activity2);
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_activityx);
```

Options select R.menu.item1,2,x

2 Solution : 
Create custom toolbar : into "android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar" and can you managment all icons.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Toolbar Title"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                android:src="@drawable/sun"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

In your menu XML file, you can add a menu item not visible (android:visible=false) and render visible when you want.

Comment: how do you render this visible?

Comment: @Chief get the item id, and then set its visibility